# How to create a desktop shortcut/icon that links to my website

Tags: javascript, actionscript, batch-file, desktop, shortcut

I am looking for a way for users to download a shortcut to their desktop which links directly to my website.

I need the shortcut for mac and pc with an image icon, is this possible.

Has anyone got any experience at doing this?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: A shortcut? You mean a .url file or what?

Comment: You go to your website and save the page from the browser. File -> Save.. I think this is what you're looking for.

Comment: You can just let users drag an anchor link from your page: `<a href="http://www.example.com">Drag me to the desktop!</a>`

Comment: @MaxArt not sure the extact extension for mac / pc, but looking for more of a .webloc / .ico type file that links to my webpage. what does .url do ?

--reos I know the user can go to File > Save but i want a message that pops up on my website saying : do u want to save as an icon to your home screen. When they click the icon on the home screen, it will open the website in your default browser. Would be useful for us. As users wouldn't have to save the page and attach a logo themselves.

Comment: @Saebekassebil but there is no image on it. just a icon saying html page..

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to look inside an .URL file, is to open it inside Notepad. The content (in its simplest form) of an Internet Shortcut could look like this:

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=http://example.org/page.html
```

As you can see, .URL files have an INI file format. The URL represents the address location of the page to load. It must specify a fully qualifying URL with the format protocol://server/page. 
For other possible fields, I suggest you to take a look at "An Unofficial Guide to the URL File Format".

To add icon use something like this (within your .url file):

```
IconIndex=0
IconFile=C:\Windows\System32\Shell32.dll
```

Here shell32.dll is file containing icons as resources.

Answer (score 0):

Have been told that i will need to write an applescript script or a batch file in order to open the website and contain an icon image otherwise the user will have to add their own image.

Here is a link with some more info for Applescript: 
[Mac-programming-web-scripting](http://macosx.com/forums/software-programming-web-scripting/35377-using-applescript-open-web-browser-go-site.html)

Comment: How do you hope that an applescript will work for Windows and Linux too?

Comment: Have to have two different applications:  applescript saved as a .app for mac, and a batch converted into an .exe file for windows.